# Making a juniper VPN work on linux

Tags: linux, perl, vpn

I've tried several tools, the original scripts (ncsvc and ncui) do not output any error message to know what wrong with connection, even with wireshark I could not know what was wrong. The best tool I found so far is [jvpn](https://smallhacks.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/jvpn-perl-script-to-connect-to-the-juniper-vpn-with-host-checker-enabled/) written in Perl, however I got a `Status=6e` error (other users seem to have the same error), unfortunately the developer seems not to have time to fix it, here are the logs of ncsvc and ncui modes hoping that someone else had have the same issue:

[ncsvc stdout](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cxQgU1V7) and [ncui stdout](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=00rCcZ5J)

Answer (score 1):

We're working on adding Juniper support to the OpenConnect VPN client: http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/

For now, until we complete the authentication support in OpenConnect itself, it's being invoked by another script similar to the ones you've been trying: https://github.com/russdill/juniper-vpn-py

Could I get you to try that, and let us know your results? We should be able to make this work, and when the dust has settled you should have fully integrated NetworkManager support just like we have for Cisco AnyConnect (and command line too, of course).

We're on the #openconnect IRC channel on FreeNode, and the openconnect-devel@lists.infradead.org mailing list.

Comment: I used to use the following command with ncsvc:
./ncsvc -h my.host.com -u "USER" -p "s3cr3t" -r "Realm" -f ./company.cert -U 'https://my.host.com/dana-na/auth/url_default/welcome.cgi'
How can I replace it using your juniper-vpn.py script?

Answer (score 1):

I was also hitting this error and discovered it is a race condition I managed to work around by both enabling the debugging mode (i.e. `debug=1` in `jvpn.ini`, which you've obviously already done) and letting `jvpn` start `ncsvc` with `strace`, i.e. replace this line in `jvpn.pl`

```
system("./ncsvc >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

by

```
system("strace ./ncsvc >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

It's a heisenbug. Full solution here: https://github.com/AurelienLourot/jvpn

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [msjnc](http://mad-scientist.us/juniper.html)? I've been using that for a couple of years from my Debian box to get into my employer's Juniper VPN. The instructions on the referenced site are pretty thorough.

Comment: I tried msjnc it does not connect at all, worst, it does not show any debug message!